# Unable to find a specification for 'Firebase' (IOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, installation, cocoapods

I am adding cocoa pods to my ios project (swift). 
I have initalized the pods in the project directory using 'pod init myproject.xcodeproj'. I then added pod 'Firebase' to the Podfile as such:

```
project 'HOTS IOS.xcodeproj/'

platform : ios, '9.0'

target 'HOTS IOS' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase'

  target 'HOTS IOSTests' do 
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
  end

  target 'HOTS IOSUITests' do 
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
  end

end
```

Now when I run pod install i get the error: Unable to find a specification for 'Firebase'.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what Firebase service you want to use you have to add different Firebase services in your podfile. "'Firebase'" is not a valid pod.

**pod 'Firebase/Core'** is the most basic and will give you the prerequisite libraries needed to get Firebase running. If you want to use other services you can choose between these pods:

**pod 'Firebase/Core'** --> Prerequisite libraries and Analytics

**pod 'Firebase/AdMob'** --> AdMob

**pod 'Firebase/Messaging'** --> Cloud Messaging / Notifications

**pod 'Firebase/Database'** --> Realtime Database

**pod 'Firebase/Invites'** --> Invites

**pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'** --> Dynamic Links

**pod 'Firebase/Crash'** --> Crash Reporting

**pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'** --> Remote Config

**pod 'Firebase/Auth'** --> Authentication

**pod 'Firebase/Storage'** --> Storage

(Note: without --> text. Only add for example pod 'Firebase/Database')

**Here is the documentation for setting up iOS:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup